Cartopy add-geometries with log-normal values shows too light colours
I am trying to plot data (.csv) per municipality (.shp) on a map from Scandinavia using contourf. This data has a big range in values (see list all the way at the bottom), for which I use a log-scale to also show the level of detail in the lower values. The code I use worked fine until recently. See image below on the left.
However, when I run the exact same code now, the maps show too light colouring, which does not match either the values of the data or the colourbar (see image below on the right). I assume this has something to do with a version update, but I cannot figure out how to fix it to show the data with the right colours in the map.
 
If there is an easier way to display the values on a logarithmic scale I am also all ears!
This is my code:
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import cartopy
from cartopy.io import shapereader
import matplotlib
import pandas
import geopandas
import cartopy.io.img_tiles as cimgt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.feature as feature
import shapely

projection = ccrs.Mercator()
transform = ccrs.PlateCarree()
extent = [4.5, 31.9, 54.7, 71.24]
cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('Reds')

# Get borders
resolution = '10m'
category = 'cultural'
name = 'admin_0_countries'

shpfilename = shapereader.natural_earth(resolution, category, name)
shpfilenamemunicipalities = '/path/to/ScandinaviaKommuner.shp'

# Read the shapefile using geopandas
df = geopandas.read_file(shpfilename)
df2 = geopandas.read_file(shpfilenamemunicipalities)

# Select the countries of interest
scan3 = df[ df['ADMIN'].isin(['Norway', 'Finland', 'Sweden']) ]
scan3_dissolved = scan3.dissolve(by='LEVEL')
poly = [scan3_dissolved['geometry'].values[0]]

# Create the mask
stamen_terrain = cimgt.Stamen('terrain_background')
st_proj = stamen_terrain.crs  #projection used by Stamen images
ll_proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()

def rect_from_bound(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax):
    """Returns list of (x,y)'s for a rectangle"""
    xs = [xmax, xmin, xmin, xmax, xmax]
    ys = [ymax, ymax, ymin, ymin, ymax]
    return [(x, y) for x, y in zip(xs, ys)]

pad1 = .1  #padding, degrees unit
exts = [poly[0].bounds[0] - pad1, poly[0].bounds[2] + pad1, poly[0].bounds[1] - pad1, poly[0].bounds[3] + pad1];
msk = Polygon(rect_from_bound(*exts)).difference(poly[0].simplify(0.01))
msk_stm  = st_proj.project_geometry(msk, ll_proj)  # project geometry to the projection used by stamen

# Load the .csv data
firedata = pandas.read_csv('/path/to/countrylevel_firedata.csv', delimiter=';', decimal='.')
firedatamunicipalities = pandas.read_csv('/path/to/municipalitylevel_firedata.csv', delimiter=';', decimal='.')

# Subset .csv data
countries = firedata['Country'].tolist()
municipalities = firedatamunicipalities['Municipality'].tolist()
fireextents = firedatamunicipalities['FireIntensity'].tolist()

# Normalise the fire data to between 0 and 1 to extract the colour and log transform
fireextents_log = list(range(0,966))
for fireextent, log in zip(fireextents, fireextents_log):
    if fireextent>0:
        fireextents_log[log] = np.log(fireextent)
    else:
        fireextents_log[log] = np.nan

fireextents_norm = (fireextents_log-np.nanmin(fireextents_log))/(np.nanmax(fireextents_log) - np.nanmin(fireextents_log))

# Create a plot
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 1,
                        subplot_kw = {'projection': projection},
                        layout='constrained')

axs.set_extent(extent)
axs.add_feature(feature.BORDERS, linewidth=2.5, zorder=15)
axs.set_extent(extent)
axs.axis('off')
axs.add_geometries(shapely.get_parts(poly[0]), crs=transform, facecolor='none',
                      edgecolor='black', linewidth=2.5, zorder=18)
axs.add_geometries(msk_stm, st_proj, facecolor='#f3f8ff', edgecolor='none',
                      zorder=16)

for municipality, fireextent_norm in zip(municipalities, fireextents_norm):
    poly3 = df2.loc[df2['Municipali'] == municipality]['geometry'].values
    if fireextent_norm > 0:
        rgba2 = cmap(fireextent_norm)
    else:
        rgba2 = 'white'
    axs.add_geometries(poly3, crs=transform, facecolor=rgba2, edgecolor='black', linewidth=1, zorder=14)

dummy_scat = axs.scatter(fireextents, fireextents, c=fireextents, cmap=cmap, zorder=0,
                          norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm())
cbar = fig.colorbar(dummy_scat, ax=axs, orientation='horizontal', shrink=1, pad=0.01)
cbar.set_label('Fire intensity (ha burnt forest/fire) \nover the period 2008-2024', size=65, labelpad=15)
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=60)

plt.show()

A part of the fire extents data to show the big range in values below. As can be seen, the values do reach the 10³ range, and should be displayed as such:
print(fireextents)
>>> [4183.6667, 1378.0, 1065.0, 991.6, 908.0, 612.0, 548.0625, 520.0, 412.7778, 331.0, 324.0, 280.5, 259.3333, 259.0, 234.0, 222.0, 212.6667, 199.0, 169.0, 158.3333, 153.5, 148.6, 147.5, 145.0, 133.8, 130.0, 108.3333, 105.25, 103.0, 103.0, 90.0, 86.0, 84.3, 82.1667, 80.6, 80.0, 79.8571, 75.0, 74.0, 71.0, 65.3, 63.0, 59.6, 58.0, 58.0, 57.6667, 55.0, 55.0, 54.9, 54.8636, 53.25, 51.0, 50.4667, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 48.7143, 48.0, 47.1071, 47.0, 46.5, 46.0, 45.0, 43.0, 42.2, 42.0, 41.0, 40.0, 38.2, 35.4, 34.9, 34.9, 34.5, 34.0, 34.0, 34.0, 33.8, 33.0, 33.0, 33.0, 32.8, 32.0, 31.0, 30.3333, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 29.6667, 29.5, 29.4, 29.3, 29.2857, 28.1667, 28.0, 28.0, 28.0, 27.0, 27.0, 26.0, 26.0, 26.0, 26.0, 26.0, 26.0, 25.8, 25.0, 25.0, 25.0, 25.0, 24.6, 24.5, 24.0, 24.0, 23.5, 23.1429, 23.0, 23.0, 22.0, 21.3, 19.0, 19.0, 19.0, 19.0, 19.0, 18.0, 17.5, 17.0, 16.5, 15.9167, 15.8, 15.5, 15.5, 15.3, 15.0714, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 14.5, 14.0, 13.5, 13.3333, 13.0, 12.5, 12.5, 12.2941, 12.0588, 12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 11.6, 11.0, 10.6667, 10.0, 9.6667, 9.6667, 9.5, 9.5, 9.0, 8.5714, 8.5, 8.3, 7.1667, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 6.6, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 5.5, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 4.5, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 3.75, 3.5, 3.5, 3.4, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.5, 2.2, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.5, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ... 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]


I think this example is relevant and could simplify what you are trying to do https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/gallery/scalar_data/geometry_data.html#sphx-glr-gallery-scalar-data-geometry-data-py

(1) you say you are using contourf, but your code does not use contourf. (2) you do use add_geometries, which takes facecolor=facecolor_polygon, but your code never defines facecolor_polygon. Perhaps creating a [MCVE] that demonstrates your problem would help here

@tmdavison, ah sorry. Tried to take all the non-relevant parts out of the code. Am using contourf on a different plot, so should've removed that. facecolor of the polygon is set to 'none', I have added those lines now.

and what's cmap3?

@tmdavison I tested the minimal functioning code and it should be correct now! Sorry for the trouble with the mistakes with copy-paste. Learned my lesson...

@RuthC, I am unsure how to follow that code with a shapefile with the geometries and separate .csv file with the data values. Would it in that case be easier to assign the data values to the attribute table from the shapefile and follow the code you sent?

My example creates a list of geometries and a list of numbers (geometries and population_estimates), which then get passed to add_geometries.  Although the population numbers came from the shapefile in that example, they do not need to.

I got it working with your example, thanks @RuthC!
